# If projection is injection, then factor is singleton

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

I am reading this proof in the link below. Can't seem to see how the conclusion follows.

> Let $S_1, S_2, \ldots, S_n$ be nonempty sets with $S = \prod_{i \mathop = 1}^n S_i$. Let $\operatorname{pr}_j: S \to S_j$ be the $j$th projection on $S$.

> Let $\operatorname{pr_j}$ be an injection. Then for all $x, y \in S, \ \operatorname{pr}_j(x) = \operatorname{pr}_j(y) \implies x = y$. If $x = (x_1, \ldots,x_{j -1}, z, x_{j+1}, \ldots, x_n)$ and $y = (y_1, \ldots,y_{j -1}, z, y_{j+1}, \ldots, y_n)$, then $\operatorname{pr}_j(x) = \operatorname{pr}_j(y) = z.$ It follows that $x_k = y_k$ for all $k \ne j$ meaning $S_k$ is a singleton for any $k \ne j.$

I am not sure how $S_k$ is a singleton follows from $x_k = y_k, \ k \ne j.$ I can see that happenning if $S_k = \{x_k, y_k\}$, but that doesn't look correct. Can, someone, please, elaborate on this. Thanks.

https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Projection_is_Injection_iff_Factor_is_Singleton#Necessary_Condition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any $k \not= j$, let $a, b \in S_k$. Consider the elements $x = (x_1, \dots, x_{j - 1}, z, x_{j + 1}, \dots, x_n)$, $y = (y_1, \dots, y_{j - 1}, z, y_{j + 1}, \dots, y_n)$ with $x_k = a$, $y_k = b$. By construction, we have $\mathrm{pr}_j(x) = \mathrm{pr}_j(y)$, so $x = y$ and hence $a = x_k = y_k = b$.

To be a bit less formal, your projection map $\mathrm{pr}_j$ being injective is telling you that there can only be one choice for the other coordinates, so the sets they lie in must be singletons.

Comment: Are we implicitly assuming induction here meaning $a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_n \in S_k \implies a_1 = a_2 = \ldots =a_n?$

Comment: No, we are showing that any two elements in $S_k$ are the same. Here is an argument as to why that gives that $S_k$ is a singleton. Pick $x \in S_k$ then I claim $S_k = \{x\}$. It is clear $\{x\} \subseteq S_k$, and if $y \in S_k$ then by our argument $y = x \in \{x\}$, so $S_k \subseteq \{x\}$.